# What function can I use consistently to escape possible HTML for editing and display?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm very new to WP, and from following books and online examples, I have several different 'esacping' functions in my first plugin. I would like to know if there is one function, or a minimal set of functions, I can use to prevent malicious HTML stored in my DB from doing anything bad. I would, however, always like to store text exactly as it is captured, and only sanitize it when presenting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would start with the one called [**`esc_html()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html).

**EDIT**

Longer answer:

You should perform *sanitization* on *input*, and *escaping* on *output*.

To **sanitize HTML** content on *input*, I would use one of the `kses()` family of filters - particularly, [**`wp_kses_post()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post), which will filter all but the HTML tags allowed via the Post Editor.

To **escape HTML** content on *output*, I would use [**`esc_html()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html), which escapes HTML blocks for output.